# How can I sort child nodes by property value in Scala.js?

Tags: sorting, nodes, scala.js

The problem is to sort all child divs of a root node according to their `top` CSS property.

Here is my code:

```
val elements = global.document.getElementById("root").childNodes.asInstanceOf[dom.NodeList]

val clones = (for (i <- (0 to (elements.length - 1)) if (elements(i).isInstanceOf[dom.raw.HTMLDivElement])) yield {
  val clone = elements(i).cloneNode(true)
  val style = clone.attributes.getNamedItem("style").value
  val parts = style.split("top: ")
  val parts2 = parts(1).split("px")
  val px = parts2(0).toDouble
  Tuple2[dom.Node, Double](clone, px)
}).toList

val sorted = clones.sortWith((a, b) => a._2 > b._2)

global.document.getElementById("root").innerHTML = ""

for (e <- sorted) {
  global.document.getElementById("root").appendChild(e._1)
}
```

I'm new to Scala.js and it took quite an effort to come up with this solution. It compiles and seems to work, however I'm not sure how legitimate it is.

For example I can only get the `top` property of the node in a very complicated way. Also I suspect that for deleting all child nodes `global.document.getElementById("root").innerHTML = ""` is a backdoor way. I'm not sure if this sorting can be done in place without creating clones. I welcome any suggestions for improvement and I hope that some beginner out there may find even this code useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various suggestions, some pertaining to Scala and some to the underlying browser environment:

First, jQuery ([actual JavaScript library](http://api.jquery.com)) ([Scala.js facade](https://index.scala-lang.org/jducoeur/jquery-facade)) is your friend. Trying to do anything with the raw DOM is a pain in the ass, and I don't recommend it for anything but the simplest toy applications. (This has nothing to do with Scala.js, mind -- that's just the reality of working in the browser, and is all true of JavaScript as well.)

Using jQuery, getting the elements is just:

```
val elements = $("root").children
```

Second, essentially nobody loops using indexes in Scala like that -- it's legal, but extremely rare. Instead, you get each element directly in the for. And you can stick the value assignments right into the for itself, keeping the `yield` clause clean.

jQuery lets you get at CSS properties directly. (Although I *think* you still have to parse out the "px".) Again, everything is much harder if you try to use the raw DOM functions.

And it's very rare to spell out `Tuple2` -- you just use parens for a tuple. Putting it all together, it would look *something* like this:

```
for {
  element <- elements
  if (element.isInstanceOf[dom.raw.HTMLDivElement])
  clone = element.clone()
  top = clone.css("top")
  px = top.dropRight(2).toDouble
}
  yield (clone, px)
```

Mind, I haven't actually tried out the above code -- there are probably some bugs -- but that's more like what idiomatic Scala.js + jQuery code would look like, and is worth considering as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions. I'm actually aware that Scala.js.has a jQuery extension, however I simply cannot import this extension: https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js-jquery, I get all kind of cryptic error messages about bundling. D3.js extension is simple to import and works as charm and I use this for selections currently. I would appreciate any help as to how to import jQuery ( a full working example may be ). Further complicates things that I use an integrated project where client and server ( + shared code ) are compiled together: https://github.com/vmunier/play-with-scalajs-example.

Comment: Well, use of vmunier's library is pretty bog-standard -- I use it myself.  I recommend using the newer jquery-facade (linked above) instead of the older scala-js-jquery.  But I don't know where the bundle errors are coming from -- that's kind of weird.  I'm going to be heading out shortly, but I'd recommend bringing this up on the scala-js/scala-js Gitter channel (which is the heart of the Scala.js community), and post the errors you're seeing -- folks there may be able to help.

Comment: Also, in case it isn't obvious: keep in mind that it isn't any sort of jQuery *extension*, it's just a facade.  You still need to include jQuery itself, before your Scala.js code.  The Scala.js facade (whether you use scala-js-jquery or jquery-facade) just tells the Scala code how to *use* jQuery.